# Rendering returned Solidity mapping values in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum, solidity

Here is a Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract SomeContract {

  address public manager;
  uint public theNumberNine;
  mapping (string => mapping (address => uint)) public stringToAddrToInt;

  constructor() {
    manager = msg.sender;
    theNumberNine = 9;
  }

  function setInt(string memory someString) public {
    stringToAddrToInt[someString][msg.sender] = theNumberNine;
  }

  function getIntFromMapping(string memory someString) public view returns (uint) {
    return stringToAddrToInt[someString][msg.sender];
  }
}
```

Here is a JSX frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import SomeContract from 'someContract';
import Web3 from 'web3';

class SomeClass extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const { address, myString } = props.query;
    const contractInstance = SomeContract(address);
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      'https://kovan.infura.io/my-endpoint-here'
    );
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await contractInstance.methods.setInt(myString).send({
      from: accounts[0]
    });
    const intFromSolidity = await contractInstance.methods.getIntFromMapping(myString).call();

    return { intFromSolidity };
  }

  onSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(this.props.intFromSolidity);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button basic onClick={this.onSubmit}>
        I should output 9
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected output: 9
Actual output: undefined

The console log is undefined, but when calling getIntFromMapping in Remix, it outputs 9 as expected. I would appreciate a little enlightenment on the reason for this behavior, and how to properly return solidity mapping values for use in React components.

Comment: In your component you have `getIntfromMapping` (lowercase F). JavaScript is case sensitive. Is that a typo here or is your code actually wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on next.js version that you are using, you might need to return from initialProps like this

```
return { props:{intFromSolidity} }
```

Since u are using next 12, getInitialProps might be causing issues. I converted to functional component and you dont need to use getInitialProps.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  //useEffect runs before compoent is loaded, so when loaded provider will be available
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState(null);
  const [solidityInt, setSolidityInt] = useState(null);
  const { address, myString } = props.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadContract = async () => {
      setProvider(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "https://kovan.infura.io/my-endpoint-here"
        )
      );

      if (provider) {
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        setAccounts(accounts);
        const contractInstance = SomeContract(address);
        await contractInstance.methods.setInt(myString).send({
          from: accounts[0],
        });
        const intFromSolidity = await contractInstance.methods
          .getIntFromMapping(myString)
          .call();
        setSolidityInt(intFromSolidity);
      }
    };
    await loadContract();
  }, [provider]);

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(intFromSolidity);
  };

  return (
    <Button basic onClick={onSubmit}>
      I should output 9
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: in this example I put intFromSolidity into props. If I call it directly from the component it returns 0.

Comment: @nomadj did u try this return { props:{intFromSolidity} }

Comment: I did, it is still undefined

Comment: @nomadj what  next.js version did u install

Comment: next version is 12.0.1. Other data types are no problem, it is only when trying to bring in values from mappings.

Comment: before returning, can you console.log("intFromSolidity ", intFromSolidity ). see what u are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240555/discussion-between-nomadj-and-yilmaz).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Even if I do not use props, and call the contract method directly from the component, it still returns 0. This is arbitrary simple code to illustrate a concept. The actual code contains many props that have no issue whatsoever. It is only when working with mappings that I experience issues. Answers that address the handling of mappings would be much appreciated.

Comment: @nomadj do u mean this map : return { intFromSolidity }

Comment: The nested mapping in the solidity contract

Comment: @nomadj you said your code works in remix

Comment: yes I did. The issue is bringing a mapping value into the front end. Regardless of whether or not I use props. I regret using props as an example. Here is a better example:

Comment: To save time, please pretend like there are no props, and all the code is inside onSubmit. I'm sorry my previous comments did not convey this properly

Comment: @nomadj I see now. Your code looks correct. I suggest u to run await calls in try/catch and catch the error. let's see if you are getting any error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As mentioned, this is arbitrary code to illustrate a concept. My real projects do include try/catch, and extensive tests have been run. I currently use a work around, where I return the entire mapping as a fixed array in a Promise.all. I am not trying to find a bug. I am trying to write more efficient code, and understand exactly how Solidity deals with returning a mapping value. There is a difference, for example, between a uint variable and a uint stored inside a mapping. I am looking for an answer that discusses memory vs storage, and how JavaScript deals.